# How to retrive all the queries added to a statement using addBatch() in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I think this is a very basic question. I would like to get all the queries added to a java.sql.Statement object using addBatch() function. Consider the below code

```
Statement s =con.createStatement();
s.addBatch("insert into hib_user_details (first_name, last_name, dob, email, user_id) values ('vivek', 'vivek', '2014-02-27', 'email', 26)");
s.addBatch("update hib_user_details set first_name='2'");
s.addBatch("delete from hib_user_details where user_id=14");
int[] updateCount = s.executeBatch();
```

I would like to get the list of the three queries added above. Is there any way to get it using statement object. I surfed all the methods of Statement from the javadoc and end up with nothing. Kindly clarify. Thanks a lot.